# asp.net treeview expanding the root node and colapse the rest?

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

i have a databound treeview in asp.net. how can i expand the root node and have the rest of the tree nodes all colapsed?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the root node of the tree, you would do it like this:

```
TreeView1.CollapseAll();
TreeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand a parent at a time on click event, you can try the following code:

```
protected void tvMenu_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode tn = tvMenu.SelectedNode;
    tn.ExpandAll();
}
```